# Why does the background turn black but the text remains purple (HTML CSS)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For some reason, a black background shows up out of nowhere on the p tags under the div when you put the CSS selector to #div1. If I fix it and change the selector from #div1 to #div1 > h4 like my little tutorial text was explaining, it fixes itself. Why is that? I just need to know if it's a glitch or not. Thanks!

Please advise. Thanks.

```css
body {
}

h2 {
     color: red;
}

p {
     color: pink;
}   

p {
    color: green;
}

p {
    color: purple;
}

.orange > p {
    color:orange;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

#red {
    color: red;
}

#div1 > h4 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basics.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the color purple not pink or green because CSS always takes the selector that is last in the cascade.</p>
    <div class="orange">
        <h1>This will not be orange</h1>
        <p>This will be orange because our selector in CSS for the class="orange" is like this: .orange > p making the h1 unchanged even though it is under the same class="orange" and the p will be the only one that changes to orange text!</p>
    </div>
    <p class="blue">This will be blue.</p>
    <p class="blue">This will also be blue, because you can use classes more than once unlike ID's.</p>
    <p id="red">This is an ID stating it is red.</p>
    <p id="red">This is using the same ID to say it is red, and as you can see it still works. But, be warned, using the same ID to multiple elements is invalid HTML and should be avoided!</p>
    <div id="div1">
        <p>This paragraph is wrapped in a div with the id of "div1" which gives a black background and white text.</p>
        <p>This paragraph is also wrapped in the div with the id of "div1". Notice that neither this paragraph or the paragraph before this one has white text or a black background. This is because we didn't specify in the selector to give p tags white text by using a > symbol between #div1 and p. In fact, it remained purple since that is the last thing applicable that the cascade found to work.</p>
        <h4>This h4 text on the other hand (which is also inside of the div as the other two paragraphs above it) works because we specified it to be #div1 > h4 for its selector. (side note: the two paragraphs above this h4 element do in fact get a black background until we write in #div > h4. I do not know why the text remains purple but the background changed to black...It fixed itself to not having a black background after we wrote in the code "#div1 > h4" so idk what to make of it...) 
        </h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

#div1 is the *parent* of the p elements. This means that some properties (such as background) of #div1 will be applied to the child element(s). However, when you add the > h4 it is specifying that those properties should only apply to the h4 child element of #div1 element. So no, it is not a glitch but is intended CSS behavior.

To note, you have 3 distinct p {} statements, each with a different color...only the final one will be used (because they all have the same specificity) and you can delete the top two.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this. I do wonder why only some properties (such as the background) work while other properties such as changing the text color to white do not?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the reason the black background only applies to the `h4` element once you add the angled bracket is because the angled bracket is a CSS child selector.

In this instance, `#div1 > h4` applies styling to all `h4` that are children of the `#div1` div, whereas `#div1` itself applies styling to everything contained in the div (including `p`)

I hope this answers your question my friend.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder why it doesn't make the text white but does a black background when you only apply the #div1 though. Seems odd right?

Comment: Of course. One thing I can tell you for sure is that when you're working with HTML/CSS and code isn't doing what you think it'll do, it is not a glitch. Code will do exactly what its directed to do (in order, mind you), which is why the other gentleman that answered you mentioned your use of `p` styling in your CSS. More often than not, you need to revise your code and research the fundamentals of the elements and parameters you're using. Good luck, my friend!

Comment: Thank you, that's good advice for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

#div1 is the part element that your p tags contain. since that p tags are inside the div, the back ground color will be black. because it applies its styles to all the child elements.
when you give #div1 > h4 ; this styles only affects on h4 tag since it only applies to #div1 's child h4 elements.